# Overriding CSS property using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Suppose I have the following CSS in a linked style sheet:

```
td {background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb,  #fafafa);}
```

This makes all my table columns green.

Suppose I have the following table row:

```
<tr id="myRow"><td>stuff</td><td>more stuff</td></tr>
```

The whole row is green but following user input I want to do the following:

```
$("#myRow").children('td').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
```

Why won't this turn my row from green to red and how can I make that work without adding `!important` to my style sheets?

Comment: @Charlie Looks like I grabbed the wrong td style in my sheet when I made this post. I've edited it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
$("#myRow").children('td').css('background-color', 'red');
```

or

```
$("#myRow").children('td').css('background', 'red');
```

Also some bizzare things to check if the above won't work:

- Where do you call your jQuery code? (Is it in some function, `$(document).ready()`..?)
- Do you have inline `style` attribute there?
- Do you have any errors caused by previous code? (see debugger - built-in Chrome Dev Tools of FireBug)

Comment: jQuery's CSS method accepts camel-case properties like "backgroundColor" as well as dashed properties like "background-color"

Comment: agree with @jqueryrocks look: http://api.jquery.com/css/ said 'Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties.'

Comment: Hmm... I always treated them as typos, as I had some problems with these - sometimes it just didn't work.

Comment: Changing my code to simply 'background' did the trick. Apparently it couldn't override just the color on a custom gradient. Thanks!

Comment: @jqueryrocks I have also noticed what Pablo Lemurr noticed...some times the camel case just doesn't work as expected. Why, I don't know.